# Is it possible to hijack TCP connections on remote hosts?

Tags: sockets, tcp

For example, let's say `Person A` is connected to a `Server` and has already initiated a TCP connection.  None of the packets are encrypted.  Let's say `Person A` has an IP address of `99.99.99.1`

Is it possible for another user, `Person B` to connect to the same `Server` and send a packet so that the `Server` thinks it came from `Person A`?

I am aware of `TCP Spoofing`

Could `Person B` using TCP Spoofing to achieve this? 'Spoof' the destination IP and guess the destination port (there are only around 5000 ports commonly used for destination ports, 60000 to 2^16-1)

If `Person B` has `Person A's` IP address, would they only have to guess the remote port in order to achieve this?  Or are there other fields in the TCP packet preventing this?

For example, send say 5000 packets, each with the spoofed IP and with a port from 60000 to 2^16-1 as well as the data `Person B` wants the `Server` to think was received by `Person A's current TCP connection`?

Comment: it makes little sense in case of TCP because you (being the person B) can perfectly send a packet "from person A" but following server's reply will go to real person A, rendering confusion. It makes more sense in connectionless cases, when one single packet having reached the server can produce some effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP creates a random 32-bit sequence number while establishing the connection(TCP-SYN). If there is mismatch in the sequence number TCP stack will drop the packet. Only spoofing IP & port alone won't help, you also need the sequence number of a TCP connection.